# The WebView ain't showing up when I run the app in my physical device

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to use `WebView` for making an url to work in my app in Android Studio. The link is basically having a `.js` extension so, I have provided the following code in my `MainActivity.kt` file.

```
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://wordsmith.org/words/quote.js")
        myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView,
                request: WebResourceRequest
            ): Boolean {
                view.loadUrl(request.toString())
                return true
            }
        }
```

And I have also entered the following code into my `AndroidManifest.xml` file in order to give access to internet.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Still the `WebView` isn't working as it shall. Is there something that I'm missing out or any else solutions?

[Click here to check out the WebView code in my XML code and Design snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3jwf.png)

Comment: does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
```

Comment: Tried but still it didn't work, moreover, on setting the value as _true_, it gives a warning. You may see it here: 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LEKnJfacoYo9uWqpMKFvyvVvzWqt8Wvz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you mean but didn't work? The webview is empty or some error appears?

Also read this one:
Note: Do not call WebView.loadUrl(String) with the request's URL and then return true. This unnecessarily cancels the current load and starts a new load with the same URL. The correct way to continue loading a given URL is to simply return false, without calling WebView.loadUrl(String).

Answer (score 1):

`WebView` won't show the content as on the given link it returns the `javascript` content and `WebView` is intended for loading `HTML` content directly.

To load `javascript` content, You need to parse the data like I did in your case and make changes according to your need.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var webView: WebView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        val myJavaScriptInterface = MyJavaScriptInterface {
            webView.postDelayed({
                webView.loadData(it, "text/html", "utf-8")
              //remove it otherwise it will go in loop.
                webView.removeJavascriptInterface("HTMLOUT")
            }, 100)
        }

        //load the url
        webView.loadUrl("https://wordsmith.org/words/quote.js")
        //add javascript interface to manipulate the data according to your need
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "HTMLOUT")
        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView,
                request: WebResourceRequest
            ): Boolean {
                return true
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                view?.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
            }
        }
    }

    class MyJavaScriptInterface constructor(val listener: (String) -> Unit) {
        @JavascriptInterface
        fun processHTML(html: String?) {
            // process the html as needed by the app
            val data = html?.replace("&lt;", "<")?.replace("&gt;", ">")
                ?.replace("&apos;", "'")?.replace("&quot;", "\"")
                ?.replace("&amp;", "&")?.replace("document.writeln(", "");
            if (data != null) {
                listener.invoke(data)
            }
        }

    }


}
```

[image: working code]

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable `javascript` like this:

```
 myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

Comment: I did this too but still it didn't work.